# Disable Spring Batch single-item processing in skip situation

Tags: spring-batch, spring-retry

I have a job that processes items in chunks (of 1000). The items are marshalled into a single JSON payload and posted to a remote service as a batch (all 1000 in one HTTP POST). Sometime the remote service bogs down and the connection times out. I set up skip for this

```
    return steps.get("sendData")
            .<DataRecord, DataRecord> chunk(1000)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .faultTolerant()
            .skipLimit(10)
            .skip(IOException.class)
            .build();
```

If a chunk fails, batch retries the chunk, but one item at a time (in order to find out which item caused the failure) but in my case no one item caused the failure, it is the case that the entire chunk succeeeds or fails as a chunk and should be retried as a chunk (in fact, dropping to single-item mode causes the remote service to get very angry and it refuses to accept the data. We do not control the remote service).

What's my best way out of this? I was trying to see if I could disable single-item retry mode, but I don't even fully understand where this happens. Is there a custom `SkipPolicy` or something that I can implement? (the methods there didn't look that helpful)

Or is there some way to have the item reader read the 1000 records but pass it to the writer as a `List` (1000 input items => one output item)?

Comment: What I ended up doing was to turn off all the Spring Batch fault-tolerance, and build a catch-and-retry in my custom ItemWriter.

Answer (score 1):

Let me walk though this in two parts.  First I'll explain why it works the way it does, then I'll propose an option for addressing your issue.

**Why Is Retry Item By Item**

In your configuration, you've specified that it be fault tolerant.  With that, when an exception is thrown in the `ItemWriter`, we don't know which item caused it so we don't have a way to skip/retry it.  That's why, when we do begin the skip/retry logic, we go item by item.

**How To Handle Retry By The Chunk**

What this comes down to is you need to get to a chunk size of 1 in order for this to work.  What that means is that instead of relying on Spring Batch for iterating over the items within a chunk for the `ItemProcessor`, you'll have to do it yourself.  So your `ItemReader` would return a `List<DataRecord>` and your `ItemProcessor` would loop over that list.  Your `ItemWriter` would take a `List<List<DataRecord>>`.  I'd recommend creating a decorator for an `ItemWriter` that unwraps the outer list before passing it to the main `ItemWriter`.

This does remove the ability to do true skipping of a single item within that list but it sounds like that's ok for your use case.

Comment: So you mean the `ItemReader` would return a `List<DataRecord>` with only 1 item, and the `ItemProcessor` would batch them up until it got 1000 of them, before emitting a `List<List<DataRecord>>`?