# Understanding COMMIT_COUNT in BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION

Tags: spring-batch

I am seeing data I don't understand for the COMMIT_COUNT in the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table when running a Spring Batch job.

The job is fairly straight forward.  It's a single step with a JdbcPagingItemReader (page size of 1000) and a custom writer, which updates an Oracle database after some minor processing.  It uses a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, breaking things into chunks of 50.  It generally processes 10 to 20 thousand records.

In a recent run, there was a database issue, so there were about 15000 reads and 14000 writes.  However, I would have expected the job to be finished after the final update, but it continued to run for a good 15 minutes, all the while updating the COMMIT_COUNT column.

I would have expected around 280 commits (14000 / 50), but there were over 10000 commits.  Only after this time does the step (and job) get set to FAILED with an appropriate EXIT_MESSAGE.

It appears that the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT is being updated over and over again?

I can provide more details/code as needed, but didn't want to muddy the question with extraneous details.

One more note - could this be due to ThrottleLimit?  I currently have it set as `.throttleLimit(executor.getMaxPoolSize() + executor.getQueueCapacity())`.  I have seen that it is deprecated and will be removed, but I haven't seen an alternative to not setting it that will allow more than 4 threads to run at once.

Comment: On a (possibly) related note, I've seen TaskRejectedExceptions when starting up a new job.  The queue size reported is at the queue_capacity setting, but that is far higher than the number of requests being made any single job.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly , if a skip is configured for the chunk oriented step and the writer throws an exception , it will then go into the "single-item" writing mode for the failed chunk simply because there are no ways to know which items in that chunk cause that exception and so the only way to find out the failed items in order to skip them if necessary is to retry writing the items in that chunk one by one each with its own separate transaction. For details , you may refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50438320/disable-spring-batch-single-item-processing-in-skip-situation/50471346#50471346) for more insight.

If that is the case , the large commit count value most possibly due to this behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunately, no skip is configured, although there were automatic rollbacks, so maybe the same idea applies?